# Doctrine ORM Join for ManyToMany relationships

Tags: join, orm, doctrine-orm

I have the User entity:

```
class User extends Entity implements UserInterface, ProviderInterface
{

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Child", mappedBy="parents")
 */
    protected $children;

...

}
```

And the Child entity:

```
class Child extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="child_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var \Application\Entity\Classroom
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Classroom")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="classroom_id", referencedColumnName="classroom_id")
     * })
     */
    protected $classroom;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="child_parent",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="child_id", referencedColumnName="child_id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $parents;
    ...
}
```

What I need to do is to add in the UserRepository a condition for obtaining the users whose children are in the classroom X. I haven't seen any example on making join clauses for ManyToMany relationships. Have you got any idea or good example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would be using a DQL query, I think this one should be close to what you want:

```
SELECT u
FROM Application\Entity\User u
JOIN u.children ch
JOIN c.classroom cr
WHERE cr.id = :classroom
GROUP BY u
```

Hope this helps!